# Can I use Visual Studio product key for 2 station?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I bought Visual Studio Pro 2012, and I want to install the program in my Desktop and Laptop.

For now I just installed in my desktop but I want to use VS2012 in my laptop too.

Can I install VS2012 in my laptop using same product key? I will not run the program at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Visual Studio Professional is licensed on a per-user basis. Each licensed user may install and use the software on any number of devices to design, develop, test, and demonstrate their programs. Each additional person who uses the software in this way must also have a license.

Excerpt from [Visual Studio 2012 and MSDN Licensing Whitepaper - October-2012.pdf](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350)